# I started a small python code with selenium but my problem is to recover all the upload links of each series?

Tags: python, selenium

I can click on the pages but how to loop on all episodes and seasons and the finally print

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    import os

    #launch url
    url = "https://libertyvf.tv/series/"

    # create a new Firefox session
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)

    #After opening the url above, Selenium clicks the specific series link

    python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/a")
    python_button.click()

        soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

        datalist = [] #empty list
        x = 0 #counter

        for link in soup_level1.find_all('a', class_='num_episode'):
                #Selenium visits each episode page
                python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('num_episode')

                python_button.click() #click link
```

I can click on the pages but how to loop on all episodes and seasons and the finally print ?

Comment: Any special reason to use selenium if the content isn't being loaded via JavaScript? What's your goal here?

Comment: i throught it was easier with selenium . I. would like to scrape all the uqload links from this site for each series and each episode thank you

Comment: Can you please provide an example of an "_upload link_" ?

Comment: Exemple : https://uqload.com/embed-4spu185ss9ln.html

Comment: All the link of embedded video

Comment: This is probably better to use requests for. With selenium, you will also get popup ads and such. Your example for "upload link" is not clear.

Comment: The link is a embed vidéo since « uqload » no upload

Comment: https://uqload.com/embed-4spu185ss9ln.html

Comment: The download links are protected by hidden google reCaptcha. Even if you could automatize it with selenium, you'd get a reCaptcha after a couple of tries. This is  no go.

Comment: ok thank i use requests but problem with loop